# Php скрипт с snmp запросом не работает

Tags: php, snmp

Добрый день. Есть такой код:

```
<?

function get_speed_port($ip, $port) {

$spoid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5";           // link-speed
$community="test_community";        
$dupoer=".1.3.6.1.4.1.89.43.1.1.4";      // full/half/hybrid
$speedoid="$spoid.$port";
$dupoerport="$dupoer.$port";
$port_speed_data = snmpwalk($ip,$community,$speedoid,"20000","2");
$dup=snmpwalk($ip,$community,$dupoerport,"20000","2");
$port_speed=$port_speed_data[0];
$speedmb=substr($port_speed, 0, -6);
$dupp=$dup[0];
    if ($dupp == 1) {$dupp="half";}
    if ($dupp == 2) {$dupp="full";}
    if ($dupp == 3) {$dupp="hybrid";}
    if ($dupp == 4) {$dupp="unknown";}
$speedmb=$speedmb.'M-'.$dupp;
return $speedmb;
}

$ip="10.10.10.1";
$port="1";
$a=get_speed_port($ip, $port);
echo $a;

?>
```

На тестовом сервере (стоит php версии 5.4.9) код выполняется нормально и выводит

> 100M-full

На основном сервере стоит пхп версии 5.3.2 и на странице выводится только

> M-

в логах апача вот такая ошибка

```
[error] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/test.php on line 12
[error] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/test.php on line 14
```

Comment: На сервере какая OS?
Для работы с SNMP на Debian вроде пакеты нужно устанавливать:
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/snmp.installation.php

Comment: стоит Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
пакеты для работы с snmp стоят

Comment: Там написано:
PHP 5.3.0, 5.3.1 and 5.3.2 do not have SNMP support.